# Windows and Linux applications to show cumulative uploads/downloads for each app, at a glance

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, monitoring, bandwidth

I've read few quite a few other threads on SU, but they have been focused on instantaneous/average bandwidths (B/sec) rather than cumulative download/upload totals for a period. Either that or they don't drill down to application level.

Resource Monitor in Windows 7 only shows bandwidth.

I've just been trying NetLimiter and whereas it can show total uploaded/downloaded, it's a case of having one stats window open per application, as opposed to a table showing all applications at once.

Looking for applications for both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu), but they don't need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, take a look at TCPView from SysInternals.  It should provide what you are looking for.  More here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: TCPView, like many, appears to be process based, not collating totals per application. If a process exits, its tallies are lost. Also instead of seeing 20 entries for say Chrome (showing individual data for all processes it's spawned and all their ports), I'd just like to see "Chrome.exe 123k upload, 534k download".